# Measurability and continuity

Tags: measure-theory

Is there a way to get an example of a non measurable function defined on $\mathbb R$ ? In other words, in $\mathbb R$ what's the difference for a function between being measurable and non continuous on at most a countable set inside an interval in $\mathbb R$ ?

Comment: Can you please explain what is IR?

Comment: IR is the set of real numbers, my apologizes I am not an expert in Latex

Comment: certainly $\mathbb R$

Comment: You can [easily construct a non-measurable function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurable_function#Non-measurable_functions) on $\Bbb{R}$, but then the issue sort of becomes.. how do we construct a non-measurable set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume you're talking about measurability with respect to the lebesgue measure.

There are example of non measurable functions, however such functions are created using the axiom of choice. If you already learned about vitali sets you know they're not measurable, hence the indicator function of a vitali set is not measurable. If you don't know about vitali sets yet you can go on wikipedia and read the related page.

Now there are function that are discontinuous on every point of $\mathbf R$ but measurable,take the indicator function of $\mathbb Q$ for example.

Comment: Thank very much, indeed I am talking about the lebesgue measure.